# ActiveRecord complex calculation - how to solve it the rails way?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, arel

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to do a calculation the proper and best way using **Rails 4.1**.

*(Simplified example)*

#### Movement (ActiveRecord Model)

```
id: integer
paid_at: datetime
value: decimal
debit_account_id: references
credit_account_id: references
category_id: references
...
```

#### The Goal

I want a four column list as result, having:

1. The **paid_at** date (grouped by)
2. The **sum** of all **values** for the **paid_at** date, IF **condition ONE** is true
3. The **sum** of all **values** for the **paid_at** date, IF **condition TWO** is true
4. The **difference** of both values (Column 2 minus Column 3)

Conditions may be different, an easy case would be:

- **Condition 1:** `debit_account_id IN (3, 4)`
- **Condition 2:** `credit_account_id IN (3, 4)`
- **Just another one:** Any field of a joined account must have a field match a value
- ...

#### Example result

```
 date       | earnings | spendings |  total |
 -----------+----------+-----------+--------+
 2015-01-01 |   120.00 |     50.00 |  70.00 |
 2015-01-05 |     0.00 |     10.00 | -10.00 |
 2015-01-06 |   100.00 |      0.00 | 100.00 |
 ...
```

#### One possible (ugly) SQL way

```
SELECT
  DATE(`paid_at`) AS `date`,
  SUM(IF(credit_account_id IN(:credit_accounts), value, 0)) AS `earnings`,
  SUM(IF(debit_account_id IN(:debit_accounts), value, 0)) AS `spendings`,
  SUM(IF(credit_account_id IN(:credit_accounts), value, 0)) - SUM(IF(debit_account_id IN(:debit_accounts), value, 0)) AS `total`
FROM 
  movements
WHERE
  credit_account_id IN (:credit_accounts)
OR
  debit_account_id IN (:debit_accounts)
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date`;
```

#### The question

How can I get the expected result in a better way? And how to do it using Rails?

~~ Thank you in advance for any help! :D ~~

Comment: You might wanna read this: http://pivotallabs.com/database-views-performance-rails/

Answer (score 0):

If we split this up into two queries, we can begin to break it down into manageable scopes in the models.

First, we can set up conditions 1 and 2 in the account models:

```
# CreditAccount Model
scope :for_report, -> { where(id: [3, 4]) }

# DebitAccount Model
scope :for_report, -> { where(id: [3, 4]) }
```

These currently match your example conditions of `IN (3, 4)` but they can be updated for whatever account conditions are necessary.

Then, in the Movement model we can set up the scopes that will sum credits and debits by date:

```
# Movement Model
scope :earnings, -> { joins(:credit_account).merge(CreditAccount.for_report) }
scope :spendings, -> { joins(:debit_account).merge(DebitAccount.for_report) }
scope :sum_by_date, -> { group("DATE(paid_at)").order("DATE(paid_at)").sum(:value) }
```

Then an example of how to get the report you want could be like this:

```
# Movement Model
def self.report
  earnings = Movement.earnings.sum_by_date    # Query for earnings by date
  spendings = Movement.spendings.sum_by_date  # Query for spendings by date
  dates = (earnings.keys + spendings.keys).uniq.sort
  printf "%-12s %12s %12s %12s\n", "Date", "Earnings", "Spendings", "Total"
  dates.each do |date|
    credit = earnings[date] || 0
    debit = spendings[date] || 0
    printf "%-12s %12s %12s %12s\n", date, credit, debit, (credit - debit)
  end
end
```

Then if you call `Movement.report` from the Rails console it would give some example output.